# Ruby on rails: rake migrate down doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rails-migrations

I generated a migration that adds a column called encrypted_password to the users table present in my databse. This was generated automatically by rails using the command:

`rails generate migration add_password_to_users encrypted_password:string`

```
class AddPasswordToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :encrypted_password, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :encrypted_password
  end
end
```

I'm trying to remove and remake the encrypted_password column in the users_table, so this is what I'm doing:

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20110712172013` (thats the timestamp of the migration)
`rake db:migrate`
(Ive also tried `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20110712172013`)

I get this error:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: encrypted_password: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" varchar(255)

So for some reason, the down migration isn't really removing the column. Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just whipped out `sqlitebrowser` and deleted the `encrypted_password` column manually. That fixed the problem. I tried migrating up and down after that too, it all works fine. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct for the down migration. Don't know why it wouldn't be working. You could make your changes in your migration and do:

```
rake db:reset
```

To capture your new migration if all else fails.

Comment: I just whipped out `sqlitebrowser` and deleted the `encrypted_password` column manually. That fixed the problem. I tried migrating up and down after that too, it all works fine. Thank you for the confirmation about the syntax Chris.
I can't self answer my question because I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: All good. Sometimes some sql brute force is the way to go. Glad it worked out.